# advice using if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

I want to test if a class exists in the  and if it does then execute the script within the statement using javascript/google closure. Problem is my current code returns undefined so I was wondering if anyone could give me some advice?

```
if ( goog.dom.classes.has('html', 'pe') ) {

    var searchCtn = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('search');
    var headerWrapper = goog.dom.getElementByClass('header');
    goog.dom.append(headerWrapper,searchCtn);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is returning undefined where?

Comment: basically if i run this in the console when I know that html has the class .pe my .search class isnt appended to .header. running the script in the console without the if does append the .search?

Comment: It seems you miss an 's' in `var headerWrapper = goog.dom.getElementByClass('header');`. This would cause an exception preventing the append function to run.

Comment: Did you try to iterate over `searchCtn` like `for(var i = 0; i < searchCtn.length; ++i) goog.dom.append(headerWrapper,searchCtn[i]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'html' is not a valid element object.  Try passing in document.documentElement or use google to get the element by classname.

```
if ( goog.dom.classes.has(document.documentElement, 'pe') ) {      
  var searchCtn = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('search');     
  var headerWrapper = goog.dom.getElementByClass('header');     
  goog.dom.append(headerWrapper,searchCtn); 
}
```

or

```
if(goog.dom.getElementsByClass('pe')){
  var searchCtn = goog.dom.getElementsByClass('search');     
  var headerWrapper = goog.dom.getElementByClass('header');     
  goog.dom.append(headerWrapper,searchCtn); 
}
```